# SQL query count for each specified date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL query I am running on a mysql database that looks like this...

```
    $count0 = $wpdb->get_results("

 SELECT *, COUNT(*) as TotalValueCount 
   FROM
   wp_rg_lead
   INNER JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail ON
   wp_rg_lead.id=wp_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
   WHERE wp_rg_lead.form_id = '46'
   AND  cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day
   AND field_number = '18'
   GROUP BY value
            ");

    foreach ( $count0 as $page ) {
   echo $repid_field . ' - ' . $page->form_id . ' -  ' . $page->value .  ' - ' . $page->lead_id . ' - ' . $page->date_created.' - ' . $page->TotalValueCount. '<br/>';
```

What I want to do with this however is return a count for each value for each of the previous 7 days, so I can get results something like this...

```
value  |  01/01/2014  |  01/01/2014  |  01/01/2014
--------------------------------------------------
AA01         34              23            12
BR65         3               65            65
YR76         45              12            65
```

Is this something I would need to do with the php function afterwards or can this be done with the SQL query itself?

Comment: Imho, you should not try to get the expected output within mysql itself. Get the desired data grouping by value **and** date, and then use/format it with php/html.

Comment: That is the way I was leaning myself.  Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one should do the job

```
SELECT   value, 
        sum(case 
                when cast(date_created as date) = current_date - interval '7' day 
                then 1 else 0 end
            ) d7,
        ...
        sum(case 
                when cast(date_created as date) = current_date - interval '1' day 
                then 1 else 0 end
            ) d1
FROM  wp_rg_lead
INNER JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail ON
wp_rg_lead.id=wp_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
WHERE wp_rg_lead.form_id = '46'
AND  cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day
AND field_number = '18'
GROUP BY value
```

Comment: The date_created field is formatted like this '2014-12-01 14:23:00' - Is there a way to replace the d1,d2,d3 etc.. with the date itself?

Comment: I think the answer is rather no. I'd better leave such formating for php/html.